# Need to to run web application on local environment

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't have information about how .htaccess is works. I have below script in my .htaccess. This web I downloaded from live now I need to run it on local environment (localhost). I have windows and xampp I already configured db for this web application but because of .htaccess the web application is not working when I execute application it redirects to "http://www.localhost/xampp/" please help to resolve the issue I will be very thank full.

Application address: http://www.localhost/abc

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteBase /  
##RewriteRule ^index.html$ home [L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php?pageid=91 
RewriteRule ^home$ http://www.example.com/Home 
Redirect /index.html http://www.example.com/home 
RewriteRule ^home$ /index.php?pageid=91 
RewriteRule ^products$ /product-details.php?pageid=92&ID=2 
RewriteRule ^services$ /subpage.php?pageid=94 
RewriteRule ^SOLUTIONS$ /subpage.php?pageid=105 
RewriteRule ^ABOUT-US$ /subpage.php?pageid=113 
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php?pageid=115 
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php?pageid=115&webtolead=1 
RewriteRule ^customer-relationship-management$ /solutions.php?pageid=116 
RewriteRule ^enterprise-mobility-management$ /solutions.php?pageid=117 
RewriteRule ^application-performance-management$ /solutions.php?pageid=118 
RewriteRule ^quantum-mes$ /solutions.php?pageid=129 
RewriteRule ^consulting$ /solutions.php?pageid=119 
RewriteRule ^implementation$ /solutions.php?pageid=120 
RewriteRule ^support$ /solutions.php?pageid=121 
RewriteRule ^Company-Overview$ /subpage.php?pageid=122 
RewriteRule ^President-Message$ /subpage.php?pageid=123 
RewriteRule ^Clients$ /clients.php?pageid=124 
RewriteRule ^News$ /news.php?pageid=125&page=0 
RewriteRule ^Careers$ /careers.php?pageid=126 
RewriteRule ^sitemap$ /sitemap.php?pageid=128 
RewriteRule ^--Pivotal-CRM$ /product-details.php?pageid=92&ID=2 
RewriteRule ^Sugar-CRM$ /product-details.php?pageid=92&ID=3 
RewriteRule ^Airwatch-EMM$ /product-details.php?pageid=92&ID=5 
RewriteRule ^Compuware-APM$ /product-details.php?pageid=92&ID=6 
RewriteRule ^IStorage$ /product-details.php?pageid=92&ID=7 
RewriteRule ^Astute-Solutions$ /product-details.php?pageid=92&ID=9 
RewriteRule ^MS-Dynamics$ http://www.example.com/products 
RewriteRule ^Test-Product$ /product-details.php?pageid=92&ID=10  

RewriteRule ^News-([0-9]+)$ /news-details.php?pageid=125&id=$1 
RewriteRule ^NEWS-([0-9]+)$ /news.php?pageid=125&page=$1 
RewriteRule ^Careers-([0-9]+)$ /job-details.php?pageid=126&id=$1 
RewriteRule ^CAREERS-([0-9]+)$ /job-details.php?pageid=126&page=$1 

<IfModule mod_expires.c> 
ExpiresActive On 
############################################ 
## Add default Expires header 
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires 
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$"> 
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week" 
</FilesMatch> 
</IfModule> 
<IfModule mod_headers.c> 
Header unset ETag 
Header unset Last-Modified 
</IfModule> 
FileETag None 
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|gz|JPG|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$"> 
Header unset Cache-control 
Header set Expires "access plus 1 week" 
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: You should do a better job of redacting identifying information. I don't think its-dxb.ae would be very happy to know of your troubles working on their site.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect happens in line 2 and 3. If you remove them it should go away.

This is not a programming question. Also, [the documentation for mod_rewrite is readily available.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Hi neuhaus, Thank you for reply I removed lines 2 and 3 now page is redirecting to "http://localhost/xampp/" which is wrong :(

Comment: There is no redirect to that URL anywhere in the `.htaccess` file so it must happen elsewhere.

Comment: I checked redirection is not mentioned any where else!

Comment: It could be elsewhere in the HTTP configuration or in the PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

Change your base to match the folder you're serving from:

```
RewriteBase /abc/
```

Comment out all the unused rules, like the extra `^home$` ones. Add `[L]` flags to all the rewriterules so you stop processing on the first match.